# Intellij 13 code template for Dates

Tags: java, date, templates, intellij-idea

At the moment I am using Java 7 and I have a utility function that looks like this:

```
public static Date generateSafeDate(Date date){
   return new Date(date.getTime());
}
```

is there a way to make intellij generate this statement everytime I make a getter with a Date return type:

original code:

```
public Date getDate(){
    return this.date;
}
```

into this:

```
public Date getDate(){
    return generateSafeDate(this.date);
}
```

Comment: I can suggest add `Util.getSafe` to template and create overloads for Date, Object and primitive types

Comment: @talex ok do you know where I could find those steps / could you post them as an answer so I can give you internet points?

Comment: That one was wrong. Bit i think there is a way to do what you want

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

Go to Settings -> File and Code Templates -> New Method Body you see

```
#if ( $RETURN_TYPE != "void" )return $DEFAULT_RETURN_VALUE;#end
```

replace it with

```
#if ( $RETURN_TYPE != "Date" )
     return new Date($DEFAULT_RETURN_VALUE.getTime());
#else
#if ( $RETURN_TYPE != "void" )return $DEFAULT_RETURN_VALUE;#end 
#end
```